# Clicking a Button if a text field contains "\r" / carriage return

Tags: android, button, text, return, contains

i am absolutely new to Android development, i have found one example i am learning from.

i want to perform a Button Click or in this Case: `onClickDone` when a `\r` / carriage return  was in the inputTitle Textbox.

the function is at the

> /app/src/main/java/com/hazmirulafiq/androidsqlitedatabasedemo/AddItem.java

file

here is the source: **[Code](https://github.com/IceM4nn/Android-SQLiteDatabase-Demo)**

is there a uncomplicated way to accomplish this ?
or can someone help me get on the way ?

many thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you might be looking for a TextWatcher. You can assign it to an EditText:

```
inputTitle.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
        @Override
        public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {

            String str = s.toString();

            if(str.length() > 0 && str.charAt(str.length() - 1) == '\n') {
                //Run the onClick code here
            }


        }

        @Override
        public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {

        }
    });
```

Comment: Hi! this has to be at the onCreate area or above at the public class?

Comment: Inside onCreate, after dbManager.open(); line

Answer (score 0):

I think that changing the if/else statemend can do the trick.
Actually an empty TextBox is empty when there is no text, that's correct.
But what if you try using the string method `contains('\n);` after `getText()`?

```
    public void onClickDone(View view) {
         String myInputTitle = inputTitle.getText().toString();
         String myInputDesc = inputDesc.getText().toString();
         if (myInputTitle.isEmpty() || myInputDesc.isEmpty() || !myInputTitle.getText().toString().contains('\n')) {
         Snackbar.make(view, "Please fill in both form!", 
         Snackbar.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
     } else {
         dbManager.insert(myInputTitle, myInputDesc);
         Intent intent = new Intent(AddItem.this, 
         MainActivity.class).setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
         startActivity(intent);
     }
}
```